# Custom component appearance update problem in the Netbeans design mode

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, appearance

I design a custom component (mainly override `paintComponent` for desiring appearance) and compile it then drag it to a `JPanel` in the Netbeans design mode.

It works correctly and the Netbeans designer renders it in time and correctly when changing the property of the component. But when I modify the custom component source code and recompile it, the Netbeans UI designer doesn't update the appearance of the component unless deleting it then dragging the recompiled component to the panel.

Is there a way to update the modified and recompiled components in  Netbeans UI designer without deleting them?